# If a floor is raised or elevated, what's its opposite?

Tags: antonyms

In Japan, they raise the floor to indicate shoes must be taken off before stepping on the elevated floor. I need a word for the part of the floor that is not raised. Any suggestions?

Comment: *Genkan* floor; if concrete or tiled, *tataki* floor.

Comment: You could use "the entrance level" in either case, but if you enter the house from street level, I’d call the lower part of the floor “the ground level” & if you have to climb stairs to enter the house, “the entrance level.” .... "[Genkan is the **entrance** of the house. As we cross the **entrance** of a Japanese house, we can see a place where shoes are kept and rack for the shoes to be arranged on. This area is called the doma which can always be seen at the **same level of the ground** while the rest of the house is always lifted a bit from the **ground level**.](http://jpninfo.com/12898)"

Comment: The Japanese call it the *genkan*. It is a very specific arrangement in a Japanese home, and western houses do not normally have such a thing. Even the Chinese who also remove their shoes before entering the house don't have such a thing. At least that is the case with the Overseas Chinese. As no English name exists why not call it a *genkan*? After all we call *sauerkraut* sauerkraut, don't we?

Answer (score 6):

"Sunken" might be what you are looking for, if set below the normal level of the floor.

"Flush," if at the normal level of the floor.

Answer (score 0):

"Level" could work:

> **level** *adj.*
>
> having no part higher than another; having a flat or even surface

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Comment: How does that address the question? From my understanding of the question, there is a lower part of the floor, which is presumably 'level' (as in 'flat'); then there is a step up to a higher part of the floor, which is also presumably 'level' (as in 'flat').  So both levels are level! [Pun intended.]

Answer (score -1):

From Google:

**foyer:** "...you may hang your coats in the foyer"

NORTH AMERICAN = an entrance hall in a house or apartment..."

If you were to ask your guests to remove their shoes in the foyer, they would know that you were indicating the entrance area.

(In larger, public buildings, the North American word for this entrance space is "lobby".  Though "foyer" is sometimes used instead of "lobby" when referring to larger buildings, "lobby" is never used to describe space in a home that is a single-family house or dwelling.)

Although I think "by the front door" is also commonly used to refer to this part of a house.  My mother used to call this the "anteroom" - too formal and old school now - but as my son was growing up and he would bring a gang of school friends home, I would remind them to leave their shoes "by the front door" as I knew their parents similarly used that phrase.

"Recessed" is used to describe the opposite of "raised", but I think it's more design jargon than space-naming convention.